# Pinging from cmd

Tags: shell, go, networking

I have this app that needs to ping google.com to see if the network connection is alive.

The following works code fine and lists the directory content:

```
cmd = exec.Command("ls", "-lah")
var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &stdout
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err = cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
}
outStr, errStr := string(stdout.Bytes()), string(stderr.Bytes())
fmt.Printf("out:\n%s\nerr:\n%s\n", outStr, errStr)
```

When I change the args this hangs.

```
cmd = exec.Command("ping", "goole.com")
```

This causes an error: cmd.Run() failed with exit status 2

```
cmd = exec.Command("ping", "https://www.goole.com")
```

After i changed the args to:

```
cmd = exec.Command("ping -c 5", "goole.com")
```

I get

> cmd.Run() failed with exec: "ping -c 5": executable file not found in
> $PATH

I'm using go mod for my dependencies.
Any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The error is because you mention `https`. Try running as

`cmd = exec.Command("ping", "www.google.com")` or simply `"google.com"` should work too.

2. The reason the first one hangs is because you're calling `ping` without any other args which runs pings infinitely. So try calling it with args `-c` which mentions the count.
   This should work.

`cmd := exec.Command("ping", "-c" , "3", "google.com")`

Even better, make it faster with a smaller interval `-i 0.1` or something that you see fit. But ensure you add the `-c`.

Answer (score 3):

The `ping` command runs indefinitely, which is why it appears to hang - `ping` never exits. You can force it to exit by limiting the number of ping attempts with the `-c` argument, e.g.

`ping -c 5 goole.com` will attempt 5 pings. This is the shell form. In your code, use:

```
cmd = exec.Command("ping", "-c1", "goole.com")
```

`https://www.goole.com` fails because `ping` expects a host name, not a URL.

Comment: I tried you suggestion and updated the code above with a new error.

Comment: @pigfox you need to put each argument in a separate quotations. I was giving the shell form. use `Command("ping", "-c1", "goole.com")`

Answer (score 1):

Why would you spawn a process to ping an IP address? Try [`go-ping`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-ping/ping), one of [several packages that implement ICMP ping](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=ping).

Comment: Possibly because the entire Go program would otherwise need to run as superuser?  https://superuser.com/questions/1035977/why-does-ping-require-the-setuid-bit#:~:text=ping%20needs%20to%20generate%20and,other%20traffic%20on%20the%20system.